# "setInterval" function is dumping properties assigned in constructor function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to create an object in jQuery and everything is working fine but somehow I cannot pass some necessary properties beyond the setInterval function bc when I test it it always pops "undefined". Here is the draft code of that I have.

Thanks in advance!!

```
   function MyFunction(var1){
     this.var = var1;
     this.var2 = 2;
     this.pause = 3000;
     this.slideOn();
    }

    MyFunction.prototype.slideOn = function(){ 

      alert(this.var); //alerts the value

      setInterval(function(){ //doesnt work and it alerts "undefined"

      alert(this.var2),1000,function(){} 

      },this.pause // works again with no hassle

    };
```

Comment: alert(_this.var2),1000,function(){}   what the heck should that do??

Answer (score 1):

When you use "this" inside some callback function, it uses function scoped "this". So, try setting an "outer this":

```
function MyFunction(var1){
 this.var = var1;
 this.var2 = 2;
 this.pause = 3000;
 this.slideOn();
}

MyFunction.prototype.slideOn = function(){ 
  var _this = this;
  alert(_this.var); //alerts the value

  setInterval(function(){ //doesnt work and it alerts "undefined"

  alert(_this.var2),1000,function(){}; //100 and function are senseless

  },_this.pause); // works again with no hassle

};
```

Comment: Hey neat solution.. Thanks a lot man

Comment: selecting this response as accepted could help others (:

Comment: @MatheusMartins edited your answer. Its horrible style not to close a function call..